# What is the proper current tense?

Tags: tense

I have two sentences which in my eyes mean the same, but I don't know which one is the proper current tense is in German.

**Zahlung information aktualisieren**, I think this means, Refreshing payment information

**Zalung information werde aktualisiert**, I think this means, Payment information is being refreshed.

What would be more proper to say that the payment information is being refreshed, which reflects a current tense, because this is the message customers will see whilst that action is being performed.

Comment: Yeah, asked this way your question fits much better to our format :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Zahlungsinformation wird aktualisiert.

This is basically your second option without the mistakes.

Both are present tense, the first one active, the second passive voice.

Comment: Thank you very much! it's been 15 years since I've had german at school. Don't remember much about it. You've been a great help!

Comment: Note: The proposed answer is used for status messages; if you wanted to label an action button, it would be wrong - in such case `Zahlungsinformation aktualisieren` was correct.

Comment: @MichaelDibbets the proposal @falkb would be translated like this: `refresh payment information` and the answer states: `refreshing payment information`

Comment: Right. Well that helps with an action button I have to create later on. You are very helpfull! and it helps me brush up on my german(I'm half german myself and live and work less than 1km from the german border, but can't write german properly. Speaking and listening works a lot better for me ;-) german grammar is hard)